# ML Clustering with an added condition

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimization, unsupervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

Problem: I want to create distance-based clusters of customers where each cluster, in sum, yields the same revenue potential.

Explanation:

- I'm looking at thousands of customers spread throughout a country
- Each customer is tagged with a postal code and a revenue potential (how much will we make through this customer?)
- Aims:
  1.) Create a defined number of clusters that encompass customers located geographically close to each other (based on Zip) -> no problem until here
  2.) In sum, each cluster should yield approximately the same revenue potential -> I have not figured out a way of including such a condition

Does anyone know a way of doing so? Thank you very much in advance!!!!